# Assigning a role to a user without FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a **@ManyToMany table** [enter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9BJT.png)

The **role** table contains the roles **ROLE_USER**, **ROLE_ADMIN**, and so on.

Below I show how I create a relationship between the **user** and **role** tables.

**Role.class**

```
            @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roleList", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();


            public void addPerson(User user) {
                    userList.add( user );
                    user.getRoleList().add( this );
                }
```

**User.class**

```
            @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
            @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
            private List<RoleUser> roleUserList = new ArrayList<>();


            public void addRole(Role role) {
                    roleList.add(role);
                    role.getUserList().add( this );
                }
```

Suppose I already have a list of roles in the **role** table. Now I want to create a user and assign it one of these roles.

In this case, I'm trying to do the following:

I specify **FetchType.EAGER** (This is not desirable for me. Otherwise it does not work), then I write the following in the controller:

```
            Role role = serviceJpa.findRoleByRoleName("ROLE_USER");
            role.addUser(user);
            serviceJpa.saveRole(role);
```

If we take a look, the user has been added perfectly and the role has been successfully assigned to that user.

But as I said earlier, FetchType.EAGER is not desirable for me, because I do not want to get a million users when accessing the role table.

But if I use FetchType.LAZY then an exception is thrown:

> **Message** Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
> a collection of role: com.testmany.entity.Role.userList, could
> not initialize proxy - no Session

Here I immediately have a question - maybe I am not adding a user correctly and assigning a role to him incorrectly?

If I do it in another way, for example this:

```
            User user = new User("Иван");
             
            Role role = serviceJpa.findRoleByRoleName("ROLE_USER");

            user.addRole(role);
            serviceJpa.saveUser(user);
```

then another exception occurs:

> **Message** Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached
> entity passed to persist: com.testmany.shop.entity.Role; nested
> exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity
> passed to persist: com.testmany.entity.Role

What am I doing wrong? How do I add a user with **FetchType.LAZY**, that is, without **FetchType.EAGER**. What is the correct way to add a user and assign him a role? What am I doing wrong. I have reviewed and re-read a bunch of info, hibernate documentation, and nothing helps. How are you doing, show?

Answer (score 0):

In your user [model](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/model/AppUser.java) set lazy fetch as follows:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "app_user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleid"))
    private List<Role> roles;
```

To compensate lazy loading, initialize it somewhere in your [controller](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/controller/AppUserController.java) like below (just to give you hint):

```
@ModelAttribute("roles")
    public List<Role> initializeRoles() {
        return (List<Role>) roleJPARepository.findAll();
    }
```

Then, somewhere in your code (say a [Service](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/service/AppUserServiceImpl.java)), set the role to the user like below:

```
entity.setRoles(user.getRoles());
```

For a full blown example where you set/edit the role to user through UI, is here in my GitHub Repo - https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks

This is pretty much close to what you are looking for.

Comment: I have everything the same as shown in you and in your github.

Comment: Try to use setter for Role while saving User Entity. Also Do not save Role in the same block. I would recommend you separate the Role creation feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")}
    )
private List<RoleUser> roleUserList;
```

you can try this it may be helpful